# Erro ao pegar o resultado de um select

Tags: query, select, while

Alguém pode me ajudar com este código.

Dá esse erro:

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/xxx/teste.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined variable: status in /var/www/santa/teste2.php on line 23

```
include "mysql.php";  
$ped_venda_id = 13;


$sql = mysql_query ("SELECT pvi.ped_venda_id, IF(pvi.volume_restante ==0, 'T', IF(pvi.volume_total == pvi.volume_restante, 'N', 'P')) as 'status' FROM ped_vendas_item.pvi  WHERE ped_venda_id = '$ped_venda_id' ");  


while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 

    $status = $r['status'];

}

echo $status;
```

Answer (score 0):

amigo, acho que faltou tu renomear a tabela para o alias que vc esta usando "pvi"

```
FROM ped_vendas_item.pvi **as pvi**
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder. Realmente era esse o problema. Más o conceito do meu código não está me atendendo. Mesmo assim obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Neste código, o retorno está se baseando somente no primeiro item da lista.

O que preciso é que se em alguma linha, o **Volume_Restante** for maior que zero e menor que **Volume_Total**, o status seja 'P'.

E se todas as linhas de **Volume_Restante** forem iguais a zero, então status = 'T'.

E se todas as linhas de **Volume_Restante** forem iguais a **Volume_Total**, então status = 'N'.

Só que nesse caso, ele viu a primeira linha que volume_restante era zero, e jogou no status 'T', ignorando a outra linha que tem valor 1.

Abaixo lista de produtos para entrega.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
include "topop.php";
include "mysql.php";

$ped_venda_id = 13;


$sql = mysql_query ("SELECT pvi.ped_venda_id, IF(pvi.volume_restante = 0, 'T', IF(pvi.volume_total = pvi.volume_restante, 'N', 'P')) as 'status' FROM ped_vendas_item as pvi  WHERE ped_venda_id = '$ped_venda_id' ") or die(mysql_error());  


while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 

    $status = $r['status'];

}

echo $status;
```